# How to use jbenchx to change the int of my rsa key size encryption

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, benchmarking, key-pair

im trying to us jbenchx to do benchmark testing on different encryption methods and i cant get the @ForEachInt command to work correctly

```
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.Security;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import org.jbenchx.annotations.Bench;
import org.jbenchx.annotations.ForEachInt;

public class keyGen {


public KeyPair generateKeyPair(@ForEachInt({112,196,256}) int size) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    keyPairGen.initialize(size);
    return keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
}

    @Bench
    public Object createkey() throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    KeyPair RSA = generateKeyPair();
    return RSA;
}
}
}
```

I have tried running a seperate method with keyPairGen.initialize only and it wont work either. Can someone people tell me my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The `@ForEachInt`-command simply executes the test for each `int`-value, e.g. the code:

```
import org.jbenchx.annotations.*;
public class Main {
    @Bench
    public int[] doSomething(@ForEachInt({ 20, 10, 30, 10 }) int size) {
        return new int[size];
    }
}
```

gives the following output:

```
Initializing Benchmarking Framework...
Running on Windows 7 6.1
Max heap = 3784310784 System Benchmark = 0,83ns
Performing 4 benchmarking tasks..
[0] Main.doSomething(20)****!********** 16,3ns
[1] Main.doSomething(10)**********  16,6ns
[2] Main.doSomething(30)****!************   17,1ns
[3] Main.doSomething(10).*.***.***  16,5ns
Success.
```

As one can see, the `@ForEachInt`-statement has four `int`-values ​​and accordingly four tests are performed. A similar example is shown at http://iquadrat.github.io/jbenchx/.

There are two flaws in your code:

1. The code doesn't compile because the `generateKeyPair()`-method called inside the `createkey()`-method is nowhere defined (the defined `generateKeyPair(int)`-method has an `int`-parameter and thus a different signature).
2. The `@ForEachInt`-command has to be used in the method that is marked with the `@Bench`-annotatioan, i.e. `createKey()`.

Change the code as follows:

```
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.Security;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.jbenchx.annotations.Bench;
import org.jbenchx.annotations.ForEachInt;
public class keyGen {
    private KeyPair generateKeyPair(int size) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        keyPairGen.initialize(size);
        return keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
    }
    @Bench
    public Object createkey(@ForEachInt({ 112, 196, 256 }) int size) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        KeyPair RSA = generateKeyPair(size);
        return RSA;
    }
}
```

Then the output becomes:

```
Initializing Benchmarking Framework...
Running on Windows 7 6.1
Max heap = 3784310784 System Benchmark = 0,84ns
Performing 3 benchmarking tasks..
[0] keyGen.createkey(112)!!!!!!!!!!.!.!!!!!!!!!!!!.!!.!!!..!!!*!!..*..*...* 952us
[1] keyGen.createkey(196)!!!!!..*....*...*  1.94ms
[2] keyGen.createkey(256)!!!!!!!!*.*!!*.*.*!.*.*!*.**.****. 2.88ms
Success.
```